# Unneccessary join in jpa subquery

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, criteria-api

I have following jpa criteria query:

```java
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Company> cq = cb.createQuery(Company.class);
    Root<Company> root = cq.from(Company.class);
    cq.select(root);

    Subquery<String> sq = cq.subquery(String.class);
    Root<Employee> subroot = sq.from(Employee.class);
    sq.select(subroot.get(Employee_.lastName));

    Predicate typePredicate = cb.equal(subroot.get(Employee_.lastName), "Doe");

    Predicate correlatePredicate = cb.equal(root.get(Company_.employees), subroot);
    sq.where(cb.and(typePredicate, correlatePredicate));
    cq.where(cb.exists(sq));


    TypedQuery<Company> typedQuery = em.createQuery(cq);
    List<Company> companies = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Eclipselink produces following SQL:

```sql
    SELECT t0.ID, ... FROM COMPANY t0 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT t1.LASTNAME FROM EMPLOYEES t2, EMPLOYEES t1 
                  WHERE (((t1.LASTNAME = ?) AND (t1.ID = t2.ID)) 
                  AND (t2.COMPANY_ID = t0.ID)))
```

As you can see there is an unneccessary join on table EMPLOYEES. How do I get rid of this join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to need a subquery for the query, just a join should be enough,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#Join

Otherwise, what version are you using?  Can you try EclipseLink 2.4.

If it still has the duplicate, please log a bug and vote for it.

You might be able to use the inverse ManyToOne, instead of the OneToMany (i.e. root == subroot.get("company") ).

Also try JPQL in 2.4, is the join optimized?

Comment: Sorry, I am bound to eclipselink 2.3 because of our Weblogic Dependeny 10.3.5. I cannot change the model. I will try the join-approach.

Comment: The latest release [EclipseLink 2.5.1](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/) also produces ugly, superfluous, redundant, clumsy joins while using subqueries of certain type that doesn't happen in Hibernate. It is difficult to see whether it is deliberate or not.